# How can I get the results returned by a map function with RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am getting a list of multimedia information as part of my API call using RxJava's `map` function to create a list of image URLs from the response JSON. How can I handle the returned list from the map function? This is my code:

```
BrowseAPI service = CKApplication.getInstance().getRestAdapter().create(BrowseAPI.class);
BrowseRequest request = new BrowseRequest("0","50","true","A");
service.getMultmedia(MyApplication.getInstance().getJSessionID(), request).map(new Func1<Multimedia, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call(Multimedia multimedia) {
        ArrayList<String> imageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(MultiMediaImage image : multimedia.getResultsWrapper().getMultiMediaImage()) {
            String url = "https://xxxxxxx/service/content/imageByEntitlement/";
            url += image.getEid();
            url +="?thumbnail=true";
            imageURLs.add(url);
        }
        return imageURLs;
    }
}).subscribe(multimedia -> {
    Log.d("dfa", "adga");
});
```

I am able to create the string list of URLs from the response, I would like to handle this list of URLs in a separate activity or fragment.

Using `flatMap`, I am sure this can be improved:

```
BrowseAPI service = CKApplication.getInstance().getRestAdapter().create(BrowseAPI.class);
BrowseRequest request = new BrowseRequest("0","50","true","A");
service.getMultmedia(CKApplication.getInstance().getJSessionID(), request).flatMap(new Func1<Multimedia, Observable<MultiMediaImage>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MultiMediaImage> call(Multimedia multimedia) {
        Observable<MultiMediaImage> observable = Observable.from(multimedia.getResultsWrapper().getMultiMediaImage());
        return observable;
    }
}).subscribe(new Action1<MultiMediaImage>() {
    @Override
    public void call(MultiMediaImage multiMediaImage) {
        service.getImageObject(CKApplication.getInstance().getJSessionID(), multiMediaImage.getEid()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(imageObject -> {
            mImages.add(imageObject.getAuthenticatedStoreUrl());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: 1.) Is there any reason you don't use a `Func1<Multimedia, List<String>>` rather than just return `Object`s? 2.) Where exactly do you run into problems? You could just get a reference to the `Observable` in your `Activity`/`Fragment` and subscribe there?

Comment: Thanks Mattia , I will try observing on the Activity. In case of Func1<Multimedia, List<String>> , how can I access the values of List<String>

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what you mean by "how can I access them" - you get them handed to you as the argument of your `onNext` method. In your example the `multimedia` variable would contain the result of your `Func1`. Whatever you `return` in that the `call` method is passed along to the `onNext`.

Comment: Basically , what I am trying to achieve here is,  getMultmedia() returns a json response with List  of MultiMediaImage objects which has just the IDs for the Image. I am parsing the getMultiMedia() response and creating the arraylist of URLs with the IDs. Once I have the array list of URLs , I have to make another api call with authenticated header ,which would return the json response with the actual Image URL. I have to make two back to back api calls to get the actual image URL.

Comment: In that case, have a look at `flatMap` - in your case you may want to use it twice in row: First to flatMap the `Observable<List<String>>` to an `Observable<String>` and then to actually execute your second API call for each of the `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Observable<Multimedia> multimediaObservable = service.getMultmedia(MyApplication.getInstance().getJSessionID(), request);

Subscription subscription = bindFragment(this, multimediaObservable
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread(new Handler()))
.map(new Func1<Multimedia, ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> call(Multimedia multimedia) {
        ArrayList<String> imageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(MultiMediaImage image : multimedia.getResultsWrapper().getMultiMediaImage()) {               
            imageURLs.add(makeImageUrl(image);
        }
        return imageURLs;
    }
})).subscribe(multimediaArrayList -> {
    //do something with the list
});

...
private String makeImageUrl(MultiMediaImage image){
    String url = "https://xxxxxxx/service/content/"
    url += image.getEid();
    url +="?thumbnail=true";
    return url;
}
```

Or with Java8 syntax that you use in the subscribe() method:

```
.map(multimedia -> {
    ArrayList<String> imageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(MultiMediaImage image : multimedia.getResultsWrapper().getMultiMediaImage()) {               
        imageURLs.add(makeImageUrl(image);
    }
    return imageURLs;        
})
```

Some notes:

- I assume that the multimediaObservable is a network call which should not be done in the main thread. If its an observable emitted from Retrofit you don't need to worry to have a separate async thread.
- The bindFragment() is part of the RxAndroid library which automatically
  "observe(s)On" the mainThread(). For activities use bindActivity(). Alternatively use observeOn(mainThread()).
- There is no need as you do in the second example to use flatmap because it converts without need the object to observable and back to normal object (which the map directly can receive).
- Don't forget the onError in the subsribe().

**Update:**

You can use `from()` to flatten the array and handle per MultimediaImage item in the subscribe.

```
Subscription subscription = bindFragment(this, multimediaObservable
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread(new Handler()))
.flatMap(multimedia-> 
   Observable.from(multimedia.getResultsWrapper().getMultiMediaImage())
).subscribe(multimediaImage -> {
    //multimediaImage is a MultimediaImage class object
    Log.i("ImageId", multimediaImage.getEid());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Diolor. In your example with map, If am not wrong ,I would have to wait till the complete imageUrls list. I would like to populate the list with images as each object is created instead of waiting till the entire list is populated. how can I do that ?

Comment: @r7v Well depends. The `Observable<Multimedia>` emits a multimedia item which has (according to what I understand) an already created arraylist of images. So if you want to get the newly created images you should observe the list (`getMultiMediaImage()`) and not the Multimedia itself. But this is a deeper architectural thing in your code :) If you just want to take one image a time from the `getMultiMediaImage()` check the update above.